# ReportBro Unicode not working even with DejaVu or Firefly

Tags: pdf, unicode, fonts

I have a Django app that uses ReportBro for PDF and Excel. It works fine with Latin characters but we have requests to support Arabic, Nepalese and more.

The documentation at https://www.reportbro.com/guide/view/11/fonts explains how to setup additional fonts that support Unicode like DejaVuSans and Firefly. I followed those instructions and I am able to select the DejaVu font in the designer in my app, with its effect:
[image: Nepalese in DejaVuSans]

Same with Firefly that puts a weird space between Test and é but at least, the fonts are loading properly in the Designer.

When I save this, it properly makes its way to the report definition JSON:
[image: JSON is showing Nepalese]
(I know, I removed the "Testé" here)

I also know that the DejaVuSans font is properly configured in the Report() call because it doesn't complain about the missing font and latin text displays with that font.
However, I am not seeing the same result:

[EDIT] It looks like the browser manages to display the non-latin characters but they're not present in the font. I tried a few alternatives. As suggested by @JosefZ, I tried the GNU Unifont. That one works but it's a bitmap font intended for screens and small characters. I also tried the GNU Free Font that works well with Devanagari but not with Arabic:

[image: Various fonts]

The code to generate the report:

```
report = Report(report_definition, data, is_test_data, additional_fonts=[
           dict(
               value='firefly', filename=finders.find("report/reportbro/fonts/fireflysung.ttf")
           ),
           dict(
               value='dejavusans',
               filename=finders.find('report/reportbro/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'),
               bold_filename=finders.find('report/reportbro/fonts/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf'),
               italic_filename=finders.find('report/reportbro/fonts/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf'),
               bold_italic_filename=finders.find('report/reportbro/fonts/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf'),
           )
       ],)
```

So it looks like that I need to find a free font that can support Arabic and Devanagari, not necessarily the same one. In the near future, we will also need Amharic (which has the same results as Arabic in the above screenshot, only GNU UniFont does a (pixelate) rendering).

Comment: [Try here that *DejaVu Sans Font Family* **does not support Devanagari**](https://www.1001fonts.com/dejavu-sans-font.html). Try [GNU UniFont](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/unifont/unifont-15.0.01/) rather.

Comment: @JosefZ Very good point, thanks. It looks awful because it's very pixelated but at least, it works. I'll now have to find out how to get it to look good. 

Answer (score 1):

ReportBro doesn't support Khmer, Tai, Arabic languages and Right-to-left printing yet because the pyfpdf2 library used for pdf rendering does not support this at the moment - see FAQs https://www.reportbro.com/home/faq

Even if the browser renders it correctly printing will still fail.
Support within pyfpdf2 library is being worked on and once it is available it will be included into ReportBro as well. See https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2/issues/540